# Check Checkbox State when Label is clicked

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have Styled Label for my Checkbox and hidden the actual Checkbox.

```
<fieldset class='checkboxgroup'>
    <div>
       <input type='checkbox' id='item1' class='groupChkBox'>
       <label for="item1">Julienne Carrots</label>
    </div>
    <div>
       <input type='checkbox' id='item2' class='groupChkBox'>
       <label for="item2">Lettuce Salad</label>
    </div>
 </fieldset>
```

[image]

```
$(".checkboxgroup label").click(function(){

   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
       $("#boxofnouse").append("<div class='"+$(this).attr('id')+"'>hello world "+$(this).attr('id')+"</div>")
   }
```

});

Now my question is how do I get to check if the checkbox is checked when label is clicked?

I have tried using, but it didn't work.

```
var closestParentfieldset = $(this).closest("fieldset");
if ($(closestParentfieldset > input).is(':checked'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to check if checkbox checked, not label:

```
$(this).prev().is(':checked')
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/gAzz3/)

Comment: this is it +1 online css based example on :checked state : http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vhgqj/

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

`$(this).siblings("input").is(":checked")`